# Does taking money from government programs change the Halachic status of the family structure?

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, money, politics-government

Does taking government subsidies such as Section 8 and Food Stamps in a situation where the government subsidy is specifically providing money for food per child (Food Stamps) or money for an extra room per child (Sec 8) affect in any way the status of the halachos that take into account "soimech al shulchan aviv" (chanukah lights, Eiruvi chatzeiros)? Does the fact that the government/tzibbur is paying for the child's food,rent and sometimes even tuition give the child the status of "eino soimech al shulchan aviv"?

Comment: Could the child get the stuff without his parents?

Comment: the reason of the dinim of somech al shulchan aviv is if I remember mishum eiva. It is still relevant today despite the help of government.

Comment: @kouty. We're probably talking about different things. The Halacha by Eiruv chatzeiros and other dinin is not dependent on eivah as far as I remember.

Comment: @MarkA for iruve chatserot Machloket Rav&Shmuel makom lina or makom seuda not linked to government

Comment: @MarkA I mean  מקום לינה או מקום פיתא